# Is there a module for migrating data from a SQL file?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have an SQL file containing the data for a Drupal 7 site. I want to migrate data from this SQL file to a fresh, minimally-installed Drupal 8 site that already has all the needed modules.

Is there a module that could load the data from that SQL file and create the required database tables with all the data?

Comment: you want to migrate data from drupal 7 database to drupal 8 ?

Comment: well, no you cant ! its not the same database schema !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that makes no sense. Import it into a database and migrate it from there.